# Welcome message in "Get started" Slack section for new members

Tags: javascript, python, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to send a welcome message into a **Get Started** section ([check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQOnT.jpg)) for new users joined my Slack workspace.
Also, I can't access the Get Started to customize section: https://[workspace].slack.com/customize/get-started

I am listening to the **team_join** event and I receive this event when a new user joins, but I can only greet him by sending a message in a channel or private chat.

How do I place a message, window, or block into this section?

```py
@app.event("team_join")
def ask_for_introduction(logger: logging.Logger, event, say):
    logger.debug(event)
    welcome_channel_id = "#general"
    user_id = event["user"]["id"]
    text = f"Welcome, <@{user_id}>! "
    blocks = [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Hey there!"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Left button",
                        "emoji": True
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Right button",
                        "emoji": True
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "This is a mrkdwn section block :ghost: *this is bold*, and ~this is crossed out~, and <https://google.com|this is a link>"
            }
        }
    ]
    say(
        blocks=blocks,
        text=text,
        channel=welcome_channel_id
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section has been completely removed for new workspaces.
[Here is an official Slack support answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkXhu.png)

Answer (score 0):

This section is currently inaccessible via the API.